# How to access localStorage in store/state, namely in state using Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to access `localStorage` in the store, namely in state.
I understand that there is no access to browser `methods/objects` in SSR.
I'm trying to do this:

```
export const state = () => {
  if (process.client) {
    return {
      isAuth: localStorage.getItem('isAuth')
    }
  }
}
```

The development console (Vuex) is empty, there is nothing.
And if so:

```
export const state = () => {
  if (process.client) {
    return {
      isAuth: localStorage.getItem('isAuth')
    }
  } else {
    return {
      isAuth: 'SomeData'
    }
  }
}
```

Then he sees the server work and `isAuth = 'SomeData'`, but i need "client"
How do I access `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get this localstorage data in mounted hook and from there commit this data to your vuex state.